# Orbit Embedded in Reveal: changeSlide

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I was able to embed an Orbit slideshow in a Reveal modal. You can launch the modal slideshow from clicking on a linked thumbnail, but I'm having one issue:

I'd like to alter the behavior so that when the user clicks on the thumbnail link, the slideshow will open to the thumbnail/index that was linked. Right now, it will open to either the first slide, or if the slideshow is already initiated, to where its index is currently at.

The Orbit slideshow is initialized through Javascript, after the modal has opened:

```
var orbitInit = false;
//Initialize orbit on reveal open
$(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '#longform-modal', function() {

 if (!orbitInit) {
  new Foundation.Orbit($('.orbit'), {});
  orbitInit = true;
}

}.bind());
```

I've tried to work with the changeSlide Method, with some limited success after Orbit has initialized:

```
$('#element').foundation('changeSlide', isLTR, chosenSlide, idx);
```

Also reviewed the answer here: [Foundation 6 Orbit: Change Slide programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534315/foundation-6-orbit-change-slide-programatically) But can't seem to implement it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Orbit is no longer supported by Foundation as they wanted to move on to developing other things! 

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/14504-moving-on-from-developing-orbit

There are some recommendations in that post for different options, I'd used SlickSlider which is great and real simple to use, you also might be able to find a solution to your problem using it easier! 

You can download it here http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is actually wrong. Orbit is included as part of F6, while support was abandoned in F5. I'm working on F6. So perhaps, I need to clarify which version I'm referring to? If you read through the entire thread in the forum post that you linked, it would clarify support for Orbit 6.